# How to Fix the “URL is Unreachable” Error in Facebook Comments

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

Please help me!

I'm getting the following error in my Facebook comments plugin on my page: 
http://www.daytrading-eminifutures.com/easylanguage-codes/easylanguage-trading-indicators/52-week-channel.php

> Warning:
>   http://www.daytrading-eminifutures.com/easylanguage-codes/easylanguage-trading-indicators/52-week-channel.php
>   is unreachable.

Here's the code I have within by body tags:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.daytrading-eminifutures.com/easylanguage-codes/easylanguage-trading-indicators/52-week-channel.php" data-num-posts="12" data-width="500"></div>
```

Here's the code I have within my head tags:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="154326858006794"/>
```

I have searched Google and found solutions and I have followed the instructions, but this error will not go away.

Please help!

Comment: fb gives "FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()." error on console. im not sure this is your problem's reason but fix it before if you want..

Comment: Thank you Salt, but that does not fix my problem.

Comment: hey, there's no any problem on your comment box now. are you solved?

Answer (score 1):

i think problem on your opengraph tags.

go to this page [facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.daytrading-eminifutures.com/easylanguage-codes/easylanguage-trading-indicators/52-week-channel.php) and see whats wrong on your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Value of your `fb:admins` tag is `id` of Facebook Page, not Facebook User which is wrong! You should fix this before any "Social Plugins" can work correctly of your page.

**Errors That Must Be Fixed** section from output of Debugger tool:

> Object at URL 'http://www.daytrading-eminifutures.com/easylanguage-codes/easylanguage-trading-indicators/52-week-channel.php' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '154326858006794' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

You should use Facebook's [Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) tool to check this kind of things.